# How to add a touch down recognizer to the UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a grouped style table view. And what I want to achieve is to highlight its cell from the moment when finger lands on a screen. But what it actually does is highlighting when touched up. Here's what I have so far.

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = UITableViewCell()
    cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = labels[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
    cellSetup(cell: cell)
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    cell.prepareDisclosureIndicator()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
    let header = view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView
    header.textLabel?.font = header.textLabel?.font.withSize(12)
    header.textLabel?.textColor = ColorConstants.symbolsColor
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.section == 1 {
        print("\(indexPath.row) didSelectRowAt")
    }
    let selectedCell:UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)!
    selectedCell.backgroundColor = ColorConstants.onTapColor
    switch indexPath.row {
    case 1:
        let firstActivityItem = 
        let secondActivityItem : NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://aspetica.sooprun.com")!
        // If you want to put an image

        let activityViewController : UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(
            activityItems: [firstActivityItem, secondActivityItem], applicationActivities: nil)

        activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: 150, y: 150, width: 0, height: 0)

        // Anything you want to exclude
        activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [
            UIActivityType.postToWeibo,
            UIActivityType.print,
            UIActivityType.assignToContact,
            UIActivityType.saveToCameraRoll,
            UIActivityType.addToReadingList,
            UIActivityType.postToFlickr,
            UIActivityType.postToVimeo,
            UIActivityType.postToTencentWeibo
        ]

        self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: {
        selectedCell.backgroundColor = .clear})
    case 2:
        let url = NSURL(string: "mailto:")
        UIApplication.shared.open(url as! URL, options: [:], completionHandler: { (finish) in
            selectedCell.backgroundColor = .clear})
        //            case 2:
        //                let appID = "959379869"
        //                if let checkURL = URL(string: "http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?id=\(appID)&pageNumber=0&sortOrdering=2&type=Purple+Software&mt=8") {
        //                    open(url: checkURL)
        //                } else {
        //                    print("invalid url")
    //                }
    default: break
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath? {
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        return nil
    } else {
        let selectedCell:UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)!
        selectedCell.backgroundColor = ColorConstants.onTapColor
        return indexPath
    }
}
```

So in my didSelectRowAt I paint cells background to a color I want and paint it back in a completion closure of functions, that are triggered by tapping on those cells. But it doesn't make a good ux, because the user doesn't know, if button is enabled or not before he takes his finger up.

To clarify, what I want to achieve,
[image: Here is what I need] 
and what I have[image: Here is what I have]

Comment: Actually what do you want to do ?

Comment: I want my cell to be highlighted (selected) as soon as I touch it, but now it becomes highlighted only when I take my finger away from it (touch up).

Comment: Will you share demo ? If you dont mind I will check it and return back to you with solution

Comment: Updated the question, thanks

Comment: You might be setting '.none' to cell's selectionStyle somewhere. If it is, remove it. It will automatically give what you want.

Comment: @ArtemMisesin Check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just set your cell selection style as none.

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.default
```

When you select cell its default selection functionality works , Find out [HERE in video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zedbmuqsmynx5zn/Untitled.mov?dl=0)

You can also see my code in video. I do nothing just write this line into cellforrowat method

Comment: Yes, you are right, I had set selectionStyle to .none. Now, when I changed it back, it works as I wanted to. But, how do I change the color of this selection (to custom color)?

Comment: override func setHighlighted(highlighted: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    if highlighted {
        self.textLabel!.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    }
    else {
        self.textLabel!.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    }
}

Comment: With this setHighlighted function you can set color as you want

Comment: Absolutely @JeckyModi